# Как в Yii2 добавить атрибут к модели?

Tags: php, yii2, vue.js

У меня есть вот такой вот html код, в котором есть vue атрибуты

```
<input
      type="text"
      name="login"
      v-model="form.login"
      :class="{ action : form.login }">
```

собственно я пытаюсь вызвать модель в yii2

```
<?= $form->field($model, "login") ?>
```

И как мне в нее добавить vue атрибуты ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?= $form->field($model, "login")->input("text",["v-model" => "form.login"]) ?>
```